# Create temporary partition or volumes

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I'm on macOS Catalina. I have a single 1TB volume. I am trying to test an application which will write data to preconfigured volumes, and it does some logic based on how much free space is available on the volumes.

For example, I'd like to create two folders: `db1` and `db2`, and I would like it so that if I cd'd into either folder it and did `df -h` it would show me 50GB "Available"  That way I can test my application since it will think the folders point to mounted volumes that only have 50GB of space each.

How can I do this on macOS? And do it in such a way that I can undo the allocation when I'm done doing my testing and I'll have use of my full 1TB in a single volume?

Edit: the application I'm testing needs to be able to write to the mounts.

Comment: You can create a disk image with your app and the required folders. See https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/create-a-disk-image-dskutl11888/mac

Comment: Note that on APFS disks, a volume's size is flexible & will expand if necessary to occupy the entire partition [container].